# Is it worth calling php fclose twice?

Tags: php, performance, fclose

I have an script that is set to run once per hour.

```
$refresh_token_file = fopen("refresh_token", "r+") or die("Unable to open refresh_token file!");
$refresh_token = fgets($refresh_token_file);
fclose($refresh_token_file);

$url = 'https://api.coolwebsite.com';

$fields = array(
    'client_id'     => '007',
    'refresh_token' => $refresh_token
    );

$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$json = json_decode($curl_response, true);

if(isset($json['access_token']) && isset($json['refresh_token'])){
    $access_token = $json['access_token'];
    $refresh_token = $json['refresh_token'];

    $access_token_file = fopen("access_token", "w") or die("Unable to open access_token file!");
    $refresh_token_file = fopen("refresh_token", "w") or die("Unable to open refresh_token file!");

    fwrite($access_token_file, $access_token);
    fwrite($refresh_token_file, $refresh_token);

    fclose($access_token_file);
    fclose($refresh_token_file);
}else{
    die("Error @ Json");
}
```

As you see, I open and close the same file (refresh_token) twice. Is it worth the effort to make it close only once?

This may be overthinking; I got pomodoro time to spare. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: If file is opened - why open it __again__?

Comment: *"I have an script that is set to run once per hour."* -- are you joking? It runs once per hour, it writes several dozens of bytes and you are concerned about performance? Compared with the HTTP request, opening and closing the file twice doesn't even count. You can repeat the open/write/close sequence 100 times and it won't even hit the disk. It all happens in the file system's cache. The file system flushes the cache to the disk when it's the best moment for it (usually some time after the script ends).

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing the files are expensive operation as they they require the server to allocate the resources and set up of buffers. So it is better to keep the open file open is further work is required on it. That means you open it just once, complete all the operations and then only close it.